# i need to put the values from this code in a 20x20 matrix ,to be able to reference each row for later calculations

Tags: r

i need to be able to use the 20 vectors in later caluclations ,so i want to create a 20x20 matrix which i can store each line from my code into a row,or if you can suggest a better way to be able to reference the code.

```
lambda=12
mu=2
answer = numeric(20)
k = 0

for (i in 1:20) {
  Pi_i <- numeric(i)
  m <- 1:i
  
  k = k+((1/factorial(i)*(lambda/mu)^i))
  for (j in m) {
   
    Pi_i[j] = (k^-1)*((lambda/mu)^j)/factorial(j)
  }
  cat(Pi_i,"\n\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty 20 x 20 matrix and write each vector into the `i`th row. You cannot have empty cells in a matrix, so you will have to append the correct number of NA values to the end of each vector:

```r
lambda=12
mu=2
answer = numeric(20)
k = 0

result <- matrix(0, ncol = 20, nrow = 20)

for (i in 1:20) {
  Pi_i <- numeric(i)
  m <- 1:i
  
  k = k+((1/factorial(i)*(lambda/mu)^i))
  for (j in m) {
   
    Pi_i[j] = (k^-1)*((lambda/mu)^j)/factorial(j)
  }
  result[i,] <- c(Pi_i, rep(NA, 20 - i))
  
}

result
```